# how to run flutter app without taking so long?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, frameworks

well I'm new to flutter . I see that everytime I try to run the application it takes so long to update and show me the result , Although I'm using an emulator  . I guess it is because of GRADLE . is there any way to minimize the wasted time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my personal experience, Flutter is rather demanding on your machine, make sure you have the right hardware.

I had a 8 gb of RAM and mechanical hard disk drive (HDD). The Gradle build would 15+ minutes.

I replaced my HDD with a Solid State Drive (SSD). And added an additional 8gb of RAM. Now the gradle build takes around 1 min.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the first time you run the application with `flutter run`, it takes a while to build the application.

From there, you can see your changes if you press lowercase `r` (hot reload) instantly. If you press uppercase `R` (hot restart), the application will restart instantly as well.

An actual rerun with `flutter run` is rarely needed, only if you add new packages to your app.

Comment: thanks it really worked well with me . It only took seconds to update this time